# React JS app funny behavior in chorme and firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, reactjs

I am working on one reactjs web application. During development I observed one funny behavior. In my app I am alerting one message using javascript `alert(message)` I ran my application in chorme and firefox at same time from my local server. So when my alert get displayed in chrome at same time it is getting in displayed in firefox. I don't understand, how this is possible. To verify I ran it multiple time. But I observed same behavior multiple times.
I don't understand how client side code can execute across the browser which are running in separate processes. I am hoping that I am not doing any silly mistake here in understanding the issue. If not then this could the big issue.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what code is triggering the alert, I have 3 hypothesis:

1. The trigger is attached to some server communication eg a socket message.
2. the trigger is on a timer, or is attached to some request response that takes the same time to process regardless of the browser.
3. Maybe something at OS level which pauses the alert from one browser until the alert form another has been acknowledged, giving the illusion that they both happen at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using BrowserSync? Because I went to same thing when I used it